# how to create a google cloud scheduler as one-time job with a retry configuration

Tags: google-cloud-scheduler

I want the scheduler to retry in case of failure but not to reschedule after a successful
execution.
I created the scheduler (15/01/2024 11.30 AM) using below code, I can able to successfully create the scheduler, but the problem is its automatically rescheduling it (15/01/2025 11.30 AM) next year,

Are there any automated settings available after the scheduler is success, delete the scheduler automatically (Note: write now I'm manually deleting the scheduler daily cron based)

```
const retryDuration = root.lookupType('google.protobuf.Duration').create({
    seconds: 30,
  })

  async function createJob(projectId, locationId, cron_date_time, jobDes) {
    // [START cloud_scheduler_create_job]
    const scheduler = require('@google-cloud/scheduler');
    // Create a client.
    const client = new scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient();
    // Construct the fully qualified location path.
    const parent = client.locationPath(projectId, locationId);
    const job = {
      httpTarget: {
        uri: `https://my_api_endpoint`,
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        body: Buffer.from('Hello World')
      },
      //schedule: '02 12 27 7 *',
      //schedule: 'MINUTES HOURS DAY MONTH DAY_OF_THE_WEEK',
      schedule: cron_date_time,
      //schedule: '6 6 28 7 *',
      timeZone: 'Etc/UTC',
      name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${locationId}/jobs/${meetingEventId}`,
      description: jobDes,
      retryConfig: {
          maxBackoffDuration: retryDuration,
          maxDoublings: 3,
          //maxRetryDuration: "30s",
          minBackoffDuration: retryDuration,
          retryCount: 3,
          retryableStatusCodes: [500, 503]
      }    
    };
  }
```

Comment: As per my knowledge you can't delete a `cloud scheduler job` automatically. but you may try using [`schedular API`](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/delete) to delete by implementing your logic.